# Для чего нужен Resource.RC в проекте Visual Studio?

Tags: c++

Изучаю проект и там есть группа файлов, в том числе файл Resource.rc. Я так понял, что там добавляется .ico файлы для создания иконок. И такой подход это частая практика, в том числе тут есть вопросы на эту тему. Зачем нужен этот файл? В чём преимущество такого подхода? И зачем это всё надо? Ведь можно просто ссылаться на эти файлы внутри кода.

Comment: Можно и ссылаться, но с ресурсами — "все свое ношу с собой" — все ресурсы находятся в одном файле, путь к которому точно известен, как его не переименовывай.

Comment: Получается, это более надежная конструкция?

Comment: В определенном смысле да.

Comment: *"Ведь можно просто ссылаться на эти файлы внутри кода."* - ничего подобного

Comment: Ну как минимум одна иконка должна быть зашита в экзешник - иконка самого экзешника (если она нужна).